# Finding dominating terms

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, random-variables, distribution-tails

1) Let $f(t) = \frac{exp(-\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}}, t>0$. Show that $\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{lim} f(t) \sim O(exp(-\sqrt{t}))$.

2) Let $f(t) = exp(-1/t)\frac{1}{t^2}, t>0$. Show that $\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{lim} f(t) \sim O(\frac{1}{t^2})$.

My understanding is that exponential function dominates polynomial terms whenever the order of polynomial is less than 1 (does this make sense?) but I do not know how to approach this formally. I appreciate any hints. The functions $f(t)$ pertain to the pdf of function of exponentially distributed random variable. This however is an appendage and does not help studying the tail behavior of functions.

Comment: Use Taylor expansion for $\exp(x)$

Comment: @Joitandr How does that help? Could you please provide further hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case the Bachmann–Landau notation $f(t)=O(\exp(-\sqrt{t}))$ means you have to show $$\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{|f(t)|}{\exp(-\sqrt{t})}<\infty.$$ Since $$\frac{|f(t)|}{\exp(-\sqrt{t})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\overset{t\to\infty}{\to}0$$ the $\limsup$ is zero. The second part of your qestions works exactly like the first one, so there shouldn't any difficulies any more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the degree of polynomial does not matter then? For example, if $f(t) = exp(-t^2)/t^2$ then $\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \frac{|f(t)|}{exp(-t^2)} = \frac{1}{t^2} \rightarrow 0$  as $t \rightarrow \infty$. Is this correct as well?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: I'm missing something. Then it doesn't matter what we have in numerator. For example if $f(t) = c / t^2$ for some constant $c$, then also we have $\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \frac{|f(t)|}{c} = \frac{1}{t^2} \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. Does this mean the constant $c$ is the dominating term? How can that be?

Comment: To the comment before: You can even say more (all cases are for $t\to\infty$): If $g$ is a function with $g(t)\to\infty$ then for $f(t):=\exp(-g(t))/g(t)$ it holds $f(t)=O(\exp(-g(t)))$ and $f(t)=O(1/g(t))$.

Comment: Regarding you last comment: Yes it is right. The Landau notation means 'the function is not growing faster than the function inside the $O$', i.e. if $f=O(g)$, then $f$ is not growing faster than $g$.

Comment: Great. Moving on to second part: I could write $\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \frac{|f(t)|}{exp(-\frac{1}{t})} = \frac{1}{t^2} \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ so $f(t) \sim O(exp(- \frac{1}{t}))$. But what we want to show is $f(t) \sim O(1/t^2)$

Comment: You only have to show $\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{|f(t)|}{1/t^2}=\limsup_{t\to\infty}\exp(-1/t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\exp(-1/t)=1<\infty$.

Comment: I get it but suppose the question asks to find dominating terms, then using this method we wouldn't know which term is dominating. I can show both $f(t) \sim O(exp(-1/t))$ and $f(t) \sim O(1/t^2)$ so which one is correct? One of them is a stronger result loosely speaking. It is important to know precisely that stronger result to make comparisons of tails.

Comment: Note it also holds $f=O(1)$ in your case 2), whereas $1$ is the constant function. What do you want exactly to know? The term which is causing your decrease to $0$? Since the first term $\exp(-1/t)$ is converging to $1$ only the $1/t^2$ is relevant.

Comment: If, in general, you have a function $f$ which converges to $0$ and you like to find the domination term which is causing this and express it in Landau-notation you have to 'switch the sides', i.e. you are looking for functions $g$ for which holds $g=O(f)$, because this means $g$ is not growing faster than $f$. The slower $g$ tends to $0$ the stronger this statement is. What you are maybe looking for is beeing asymptotically equivalent, which means $\lim f/g=1$. In your case this would be right for $g(t)=1/t^2$.

Comment: In such cases you always have to be precise if you are looking for a 'upper or a lower boundary' which describes your convergence. If you're looking for 'both in one', asymptotic equivalence might be the right you are looking for. The first part of my comment before describes the 'lower boundary' case.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help! I am understanding the issue better now.